# Extjs 4.2.2 Create Dynamic Unordered List containing Ext Components

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am attempting to create basic `ul` in Ext 4.2.2 by defining a class extended from `Ext.container.Container`.

Ideally I would like my rendered markup to be something along the lines of:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        {any Ext component here}
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I know I'm missing something in my current implementation that I have based off of Alex Tokarev's answer to: [extjs 4 how to wrap children components of container in custom html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239250/extjs-4-how-to-wrap-children-components-of-container-in-custom-html)

```
Ext.define('MyUnorderedList', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    requires: [
        'MyListItem'
    ],

    alias: 'widget.ul',

    defaultType: 'li',

    autoEl: 'ul',

    renderTpl: [
        '{%this.renderChildren(out,values)%}',
        {
            renderChildren: function(out, renderData) {
                // We have to be careful here, as `this`
                // points to the renderTpl reference!
                var me = renderData.$comp.layout,
                    tree = me.getRenderTree();

                if (tree) {
                    Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(tree, out);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyListItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    alias: 'widget.li',

    autoEl: 'li',

    renderTpl: [
        '{%this.renderChildren(out,values)%}',
        {
            renderChildren: function(out, renderData) {
                // We have to be careful here, as `this`
                // points to the renderTpl reference!
                var me = renderData.$comp.layout,
                    tree = me.getRenderTree();

                if (tree) {
                    Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(tree, out);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The above does render the appropriate HTML, however I am continually getting the following error when attempting to implement this:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null` which references the following function that is called from `Ext.layout.Layout.moveItem`:

```
target = target.dom || target;
```

Which in turn comes from `renderItems` or `renderChildren`.

Basically I'm at my wit's end with this thing and would love some advice on what I'm missing.

[EDIT]
If the correct way to handle this is with a custom layout I would greatly appreciate being pointed in the correct direction for that as well.

Comment: Maybe try creating a custom layout for this

Comment: Custom layout is the way to go? What is the point of renderTpl being exposed?

Answer (score 0):

[CD..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139300/cd) is this a proper implementation? I'm having trouble finding some decent documentation around this sort of thing.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.layout.None', {
    extend: 'Ext.layout.container.Container',

    alias: 'layout.nolayout',

    reserveScrollbar: false,
    managePadding: false,

    usesContainerHeight: false,
    usesContainerWidth: false,
    usesHeight: false,
    usesWidth: false,

    childEls: [],

    renderTpl: [
        '{%this.renderBody(out,values)%}'
    ],

    setupRenderTpl: function (renderTpl) {
        var me = this;

        renderTpl.renderContainer = me.doRenderContainer;
        renderTpl.renderItems = me.doRenderItems;
    },

    calculate: function(ownerContext) {
        //needs to be here as a placeholder
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.container.ListItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.layout.None'
    ],

    layout: 'nolayout',

    alias: 'widget.li',

    autoEl: 'li'
});

Ext.define('MyApp.container.UnorderedList', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.container.ListItem',
        'MyApp.layout.None'
    ],

    layout: 'nolayout',

    alias: 'widget.ul',

    defaultType: 'li',

    autoEl: 'ul'
});
```

Comment: Of course this seems to break the rest of my layout. I'm using this to create a nav-bar (docked top) attached to a card layout and unfortunately this layout results in the body of the card layout having a height of zero.